# How to get timely notification in Flutter iOS

Tags: flutter

I have a UI where there are two notification settings. On for morning and one for evening. Both can be turned (toggled) on and off and user can change time.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Here is the bloc:

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:hydrated_bloc/hydrated_bloc.dart';
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;

part 'daily_meditation_event.dart';
part 'daily_meditation_state.dart';

class DailyMeditationBloc
    extends HydratedBloc<DailyMeditationEvent, DailyMeditationState> {
  DailyMeditationBloc()
      : super(
          DailyMeditationState(
            morningReminderTime: DateTime(
              DateTime.now().year,
              DateTime.now().month,
              DateTime.now().day,
              7,
            ),
            eveningReminderTime: DateTime(
              DateTime.now().year,
              DateTime.now().month,
              DateTime.now().day,
              19,
            ),
            isMorningActive: false,
            isEveningActive: false,
          ),
        ) {
    on<MorningReminderSet>((event, emit) {
      if (state.isMorningActive) {
        if (state.morningTimeMiliseconds != null) {
          cancelNotification(state.morningTimeMiliseconds!);
        }
        scheduleDailyNotification(state.morningReminderTime);
      }
      emit(
        state.copyWith(
          morningReminderTime: event.morningReminderTime,
          morningTimeMiliseconds:
              event.morningReminderTime.millisecondsSinceEpoch.hashCode,
        ),
      );
    });
    on<EveningReminderSet>((event, emit) {
      if (state.isEveningActive) {
        if (state.eveningTimeMiliseconds != null) {
          cancelNotification(state.eveningTimeMiliseconds!);
        }
        scheduleDailyNotification(state.eveningReminderTime);
      }
      emit(
        state.copyWith(
          eveningReminderTime: event.eveningReminderTime,
          eveningTimeMiliseconds:
              event.eveningReminderTime.millisecondsSinceEpoch.hashCode,
        ),
      );
    });
    on<ToggleMorningReminder>((event, emit) {
      emit(state.copyWith(isMorningActive: !state.isMorningActive));
      if (state.isMorningActive) {
        scheduleDailyNotification(state.morningReminderTime);
      } else if (state.morningTimeMiliseconds != null) {
        cancelNotification(state.morningTimeMiliseconds.hashCode);
        emit(state.copyWith(morningTimeMiliseconds: null));
      }
    });
    on<ToggleEveningReminder>((event, emit) {
      emit(state.copyWith(isEveningActive: !state.isEveningActive));
      if (state.isEveningActive) {
        scheduleDailyNotification(state.eveningReminderTime);
      } else if (state.eveningTimeMiliseconds != null) {
        cancelNotification(state.eveningTimeMiliseconds.hashCode);
        emit(state.copyWith(eveningTimeMiliseconds: null));
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  DailyMeditationState? fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return DailyMeditationState(
      morningReminderTime:
          DateTime.parse(json['morningReminderTime'] as String),
      eveningReminderTime:
          DateTime.parse(json['eveningReminderTime'] as String),
      isMorningActive: json['isMorningActive'] as bool? ?? false,
      isEveningActive: json['isEveningActive'] as bool? ?? false,
    );
  }

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic>? toJson(DailyMeditationState state) {
    return {
      'morningReminderTime': state.morningReminderTime.toIso8601String(),
      'eveningReminderTime': state.eveningReminderTime.toIso8601String(),
      'isMorningActive': state.isMorningActive,
      'isEveningActive': state.isEveningActive,
    };
  }

  Future<void> cancelNotification(int id) async {
    final flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancel(id);
  }

  Future<void> scheduleDailyNotification(DateTime at) async {
    final flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

    // Schedule time
    tz.initializeTimeZones();
    final location = tz.local;
    final now = tz.TZDateTime.now(location);
    final today = tz.TZDateTime(
      location,
      now.year,
      now.month,
      now.day,
      at.hour,
      at.minute,
    );

    // Schedule the notification
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
      at.millisecondsSinceEpoch.hashCode,
      'Daily Reminder',
      'This is your daily reminder to meditate.',
      today,
      const NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          'daily_channel',
          'Daily Notification',
        ),
      ),
      androidScheduleMode: AndroidScheduleMode.exactAllowWhileIdle,
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
          UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
      matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.time,
      payload: 'Daily reminder',
    );
  }
}
```

But for some reason I dont get timely notification

Below is the event:

```
part of 'daily_meditation_bloc.dart';

sealed class DailyMeditationEvent {}

final class MorningReminderSet extends DailyMeditationEvent {
  MorningReminderSet(this.morningReminderTime);

  final DateTime morningReminderTime;
}

final class EveningReminderSet extends DailyMeditationEvent {
  EveningReminderSet(this.eveningReminderTime);

  final DateTime eveningReminderTime;
}

final class ToggleMorningReminder extends DailyMeditationEvent {}

final class ToggleEveningReminder extends DailyMeditationEvent {}
```

Here are the states:

```
part of 'daily_meditation_bloc.dart';

final class DailyMeditationState extends Equatable {
  const DailyMeditationState({
    required this.morningReminderTime,
    required this.eveningReminderTime,
    required this.isMorningActive,
    required this.isEveningActive,
    this.hasError = false,
    this.morningTimeMiliseconds,
    this.eveningTimeMiliseconds,
  });

  final DateTime morningReminderTime;
  final DateTime eveningReminderTime;
  final bool isMorningActive;
  final bool isEveningActive;
  final bool hasError;

  final int? morningTimeMiliseconds;
  final int? eveningTimeMiliseconds;

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [
        morningReminderTime,
        eveningReminderTime,
        isMorningActive,
        isEveningActive,
        hasError,
        morningTimeMiliseconds,
        eveningTimeMiliseconds,
      ];

  DailyMeditationState copyWith({
    DateTime? morningReminderTime,
    DateTime? eveningReminderTime,
    bool? isMorningActive,
    bool? isEveningActive,
    bool? hasError,
    int? morningTimeMiliseconds,
    int? eveningTimeMiliseconds,
  }) {
    return DailyMeditationState(
      morningReminderTime: morningReminderTime ?? this.morningReminderTime,
      eveningReminderTime: eveningReminderTime ?? this.eveningReminderTime,
      isMorningActive: isMorningActive ?? this.isMorningActive,
      isEveningActive: isEveningActive ?? this.isEveningActive,
      hasError: hasError ?? this.hasError,
      morningTimeMiliseconds:
          morningTimeMiliseconds ?? this.morningTimeMiliseconds,
      eveningTimeMiliseconds:
          eveningTimeMiliseconds ?? this.eveningTimeMiliseconds,
    );
  }
}
```

I get notifications at some random times. I have no clue why its happening randomly at random intervals.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TYow.png